# How to add new custom field in checkout/shipping page and save it in db in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, custom-attributes, custom-field

I want to add new custom field in checkout/shipping and want to save them in the following tables in Magento 2.2.5:

- sales_order
- sales_order_address
- sales_order_grid

I have referred this link https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/

But it is showing the custom field in backend at customer section. But not able to see it in frontend

Any help would be appreciated.